# Changing the minimum pause length required before a voice command in Dragon Dictate 4

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

In Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I can change  the minimum pause length required before a voice command in the option menu:

[image]

Surprisingly I can't find the setting in [Dragon Dictate 4](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm) on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). Did I miss something or is there really no way to change the minimum pause length required before a voice command?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.